# I need to access all the programs listed in Windows Start Menu

Tags: windows, winapi, command-prompt

[image]Is there a way to programmatically access the programs listed in windows Start Menu using command line or windows-api or any other way?

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: No, not UI automation.

Comment: Explain why *"any other way"* does not include UI Automation? In case you wish to preemptively reject the solution to your problem make sure to make that unambiguously clear so that we don't have to waste any time on this.

Comment: You are right. "any other way" should include UI automation. I did not frame my question the right way.

Comment: Why would *"run the program in the background"* and *"use UI Automation"* contradict each other? Are you simply not familiar with the technology you are trying to use, and just reject everything based on a gut feeling?

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you mean by "Start Menu"? which Windows version? Any screenshot to explain?,

Comment: I have added a screenshot. @Simon Mourier

Comment: @IInspectable I was not familiar with UI Automation. Initially, I did not even notice the link in your first answer. I have started exploring UI automation. thank you for pointing that out.
I will edit my question.

Comment: Everyone knows what the start menu is, the question is what exactly do you want to read?

Comment: @SimonMourier Get the list to start with and then the file location for each item on the list.

Comment: The list of what?! Recently Added? Office? Explorer? Lenovo?

Comment: List of all the programs displayed in the start menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_(COMMON_)STARTMENU)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_(Common)StartMenu)` to obtain the path(s) to where the Start Menu holds shortcuts to its entries, and then you can enumerate the contents of those folder(s).

Comment: Note: This does not include UWP/Modern apps.